# Combining two ping command in Linux

Tags: python, linux, terminal

I have two working command that check a device up/down and copy packet loss value.

For checking a device up and down i used

```
 result = os.system ("ping -c 5 " +hostname)
```

For copy a packet loss value, i used

```
packetloss = os.popen ("ping -c 5 " +hostname+ "| grep -oP '\d+(?=% packet loss)'").read().rstrip()
packetloss = int(packetloss)
```

I know its not practical to use os.system. My question is how to combine both of the command? For now i need to ping two times just to get device up/down and another ping to check the packet loss value. How can i just ping once to get both result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use subprocess. Then you can directly parse the string you need.

**Edit:** python script is updated.

```
import subprocess

output = ""
error = ""
hostname = "www.google.com"
try:
    cmd = "ping -c 5 " + hostname
    p = subprocess.Popen([cmd], shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
    output = str(p[0])
    error = str(p[1])
except Exception, e:
    error = str(e)

if output:
    data = output.split("--- " + hostname + " ping statistics ---")
    print "\nPing output:\n", data[0].strip() 
    statistics = data[-1].strip()
    print "\nStatistics:\n", statistics
    packetloss = str(statistics.splitlines()[0]).split(",")
    packetloss = packetloss[2].strip()
    packetloss = packetloss[:packetloss.find("%")]
    print "\nPacketLoss:", packetloss
if error:
    print "\nError:", error
```

Comment: i have no problem with the string. i just want to save time by combine both ping command into single command. Even if i do like the above, like u said replace it with ping -c -5 hostname, but in the end i still need to ping two time just to get two different result

Comment: using above command still pinging the address two times. can it be just one time ping to get device up/down and packet loss value?

Comment: @Jack sorry I don't understand this `one time ping to get device up/down and packet loss value?`
But what I understand is you need only the ping output `ping -c 5 + hostname` and also you need to find `PacketLoss`, am I right ? If thats the case then why would you ping twice ? just parse the string with python instead of using `grep`. 
This should be the easy way. If not then just post the output that you require.